# Remove option from selected list based of index?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two select lists and based off the selected index of either one I need to remove the option at that index from both lists.

I have seen example of doing this for the currently selected option using the `remove()` function but that would only work for one list as the other list might have a different option selected or none at all.

Knowing just the index value is it possible to do this with JavaScript / jQuery? I already have the code that figures out which list to pull the index from and get that index value. I just have not found a way to specify an index value for the removal.

Code developed based off comment:

```
function RemoveCode(codeType)
{
    var selectedProjectsField = $("#SelectedProjects");
    var selectedProjectCodesField = $("#SelectedProjectCodes");
    var selectedTasksField = $("#SelectedTasks");
    var selectedTaskCodesField = $("#SelectedTaskCodes");
    var selectedOptionIndex;

    if (codeType == "Project")
    {
        selectedOptionIndex = $("#SelectedProjects :selected").index();
    }
    else
    {
        selectedOptionIndex = $("#SelectedTasks :selected").index();
    }

    alert(selectedOptionIndex);

    selectedProjectsField.eq(selectedOptionIndex).remove();
    selectedTasksField.eq(selectedOptionIndex).remove();
}
```

Comment: `$('select option').eq(index).remove();`

Comment: @Tushar That does not seem to be working, the option at the specified index is not removed. Did I miss understand your comment?

Comment: Did you checked if you're getting correct `index`?

Comment: @Tushar Yes, the alert is returning the correct index.

Comment: @Tushar I will try but never used either so it might take a bit to figure out how it works

Comment: @Matthew have you tried my solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Using The `:eq()` Selector**

You could use the [`:eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) selector to target a specific element by it's index and then call [`remove()`](https://api.jquery.com/remove/) to remove it from the DOM :

```
// Syntax Example: This will remove then (index)th option element 
$('select option:eq(index)').remove();
```

So in your case, you would simply want to concatenate your `selectedOptionIndex` into the selector to target selector using one of the following :

```
// Remove a specific option of your SelectedProjects element
$('#SelectedProjects option:eq(' + selectedOptionIndex + ')').remove();
```

**Example**

You can [see an interactive example here](http://jsbin.com/poxiwex/edit?html,output) and demonstrated below :

[image]

Comment: What is `index` here? -- **string**

Comment: `index` would be an actual numeric index. But since you are using it in a selector, jQuery really won't care.

Comment: Huh? Don't you have to concat it? `$('select option:eq(' + index + ')')`

Comment: Yes. The first was really just to demonstrate the syntax, the second actually demonstrates it with concatenation.

Comment: Ok, it's better to use actual code instead of syntax when answering the question otherwise OP and other users will be confused. Also, add title `Syntax` above syntax will help to understand that it is the syntax.

Answer (score -1):

This code should work:

```
$('#SelectedProjects option')[index].remove();
$('#SelectedTasks option')[index].remove();
```

or

```
selectedProjectsField.find('option')[selectedOptionIndex].remove();
selectedTasksField.find('option')[selectedOptionIndex].remove();
```

Comment: Changing to `selectedProjectsField[selectedOptionIndex].remove();` gives the error "Unable to get property'remove'of undefined or null reference"

Comment: @Matthew Ok then I added the second piece of code for you.

Comment: @lamp76I get the "object doesn't support proper or method 'remove'" with the second option. I am sure it is something I am missing from my doe but I have this working under Rion's answer so I must move on. Thanks for helping